# Eclipse Indigo no longer able to copy-paste files

Tags: eclipse

Running Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2, on Windows 7. (Java EE Version)

When in package/project explorer, going and right-clicking a file and hitting 'copy', then right clicking on destination folder and clicking 'paste' results in it triggering a code snippet being created that contains the name of the file only.

So, for some reason it is no longer copying entire files...just their names...don't know why, and I can't seem to figure out why this stopped working. (I am still able to paste files in from windows explorer...so this also leads me to believe something is broken with copy).

Other copy-paste issues I've come across while researching this seem to be editor related, but hopefully someone has had this file problem and knows how to fix it. :)

Comment: If they're editor-related, you should be specific and mention which editors you mean.  And maybe stick to one problem at a time, with concrete details.

Comment: it isn't editor related.  it is package/project explorer related.  it is one problem...I can't copy and paste files.

Comment: The sentence about 'editor related' was further back-story to explicitly say it wasn't an editor problem, because that is the bulk of google-results on copy-paste problems.   I did this so that people didn't just link me to the issues about solving copy-paste problems in the eclipse editor windows (eg. java code, xml, etc.), because this problem is not related to those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some applications, like Skype click-to-call, interferes with the normal copy-paste in Eclipse. If you have this installed, or other recent installed apps, try to uninstall them.

I've got a partner that recently had the same problem and solved it this way.

Comment: hrmmmm...good to know, I will play around with it and see what I can figure out. :)

Comment: as best as I could tell it seemed to be something like this causing the problems.